# Разница между auto в шаблонном типе и типе шаблонной переменной

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, auto

В чём разница между следующими объявлениями? Одинаковый ли код генерируется? Что лучше использовать?

```
template <auto X>
constexpr int x = X;

template <int X>
constexpr auto x = X;
```

Comment: Ну, в первом случае вы можете, например, использовать `x<3.5>`, но вот во втором у вас так не получится...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае на тип шаблонного параметра не накладывается строгое ограничение, надо лишь, чтобы его можно было привести в `int`, раз уж `x` имеет такой тип...

А во втором случае тип шаблонного параметра задан предельно точно — `int` и никак иначе. Соответственно, `x` автоматически имеет тип `int`.

Так что в таком коде получим в одном случае предупреждение, во втором — ошибку.

```
template <auto Y>
constexpr int y = Y;

template <int X>
    constexpr auto x = X;

int main()
{
    cout << y<3.5>;   // Предупреждение
    coun << x<4.5>;   // Ошибка
}
```